# Azure App Service stops accepting requests

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service, umbraco7

We have an azure app service (running Umbraco), and once a day the system stops accepting requests.  We know this because we have added logging to Application_BeginRequest, and during the 10-15 minute outage, no requests are logged.  We also log the Application_EndRequest and keep a running counter of "active" requests, as we thought it may have been related to traffic volume, however the outage still occurs even when there are 0 active requests.  The outage corrects itself after about 15 minutes with no interference.  Restarting the app service "corrects" the outage quicker.  There is nothing in the Umbraco logs (errors or otherwise) that would suggest anything is running.  Upgrading Umbraco to the latest version (twice) has not resolved the issue.  We have several other similarly sized and trafficked Umbraco sites that do not have this issue.

During the outage:

- CPU stays steady at 5-20% usage
- Memory stays steady at 30% usage
- DTU (on azure sql db) stays steady at 10-20%

This tells me that none of the above are the bottlenecks, so I would guess there is some sort of deadlock or I/O issue.  This leads to the question:  from an infrastructure standpoint, knowing the above, what are some possible causes for the aforementioned behavior?

Comment: You might need a support request to get to the bottom of it, as there could be a lot of factors, and it's hard to tell without knowing the site name and UTC time of one such incident.

Comment: We have gone down that road as well, and unfortunately didn't get a very good support rep.  But thank you for the reminder that we should open a new ticket.